# В sql запросе заменить IN на JOIN

Tags: sql, jpql

Помогите пожалуйста, как можно написать этот запрос, чтобы заменить операторы IN на JOIN и получить тот же результат из БД? И почему такие запросы лучше писать через JOIN?

```
select v
from cbas_Verification v
where v.type = verificationType
  and v.id in (select distinct b.verificationId from cbas_batch b where b.verificationStep <> 'FINISH')
  and v.id not in (select m.verificationId from cbas_ExchangeMessages m);
```

Comment: IN = INNER JOIN, NOT IN = LEFT JOIN с проверкой на NULL

Comment: как будет полностью выглядеть запрос?

Comment: сами попробовать не желаете? начните с not in, там просто

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку поля таблиц из подзапросов не нужны, разумнее переписывать `WHERE [NOT] IN` не на `JOIN`, а на `WHERE [NOT] EXISTS`:

```sql
SELECT v
FROM cbas_Verification v
WHERE v.type = verificationType
  AND EXISTS (SELECT NULL 
              FROM cbas_batch b 
              WHERE b.verificationStep <> 'FINISH' 
                AND b.verificationId = v.id)
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL 
                  FROM cbas_ExchangeMessages m 
                  WHERE m.verificationId = v.id);
```

Во-первых, отпадает надобность в `DISTINCT`.

Во-вторых, не будет проблем с дублированием записей.

Comment: всё верно, но мне кажется ТСу задали некое задание по изучению JOIN

Comment: @Konst Может, и так... хотя сложноват запрос для учебного задания.

Comment: @Akina Спасибо большое!